# Navigation Components - Fade in specific content

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

Using **navigation components**, I would like apply **fade-in effect** to FadeInContent during transition, respecting the following order:

1. *Text1 -> Text2* transition (Done by applying R.transition.move in sharedElement)
2. *FadeInContent* fades-in after 1. transition

I had a look to this article that does exactly what I want, but doesn't use navigation components
https://medium.com/bynder-tech/how-to-use-material-transitions-in-fragment-transactions-5a62b9d0b26b, therefore I can't apply `setStartDelay`. I can't also apply `NavOptions.Builder().setEnterAnim(R.anim.fade_in)` because it applies to all the screen, and not just the FadeInContent.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the navigation component can only handle the motion during the transition itself so you are rightly pointing out that there is no way to delay a transition.

Nonetheless, you might want to implement your fade-in animation with a scene transition (https://developer.android.com/training/transitions).

It looks like a cleaner way to handle the situation you are exposing.

**Code Solution:**

```
val transition = TransitionInflater.from(activity)
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {
            override fun onMapSharedElements(
                names: MutableList<String>?,
                sharedElements: MutableMap<String, View>?
            ) {
                super.onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements)
                fadeInContainer.loadAnimation(
                    activity,
                    R.anim.fade_in
                )
              }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Solution:

```
val transition = TransitionInflater.from(activity)
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {
            override fun onMapSharedElements(
                names: MutableList<String>?,
                sharedElements: MutableMap<String, View>?
            ) {
                super.onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements)
                fadeInContainer.loadAnimation(
                    activity,
                    R.anim.fade_in
                )
              }
        })
```